# Further optimizing Number to Roman Numeral function in F#

Tags: f#, functional-programming

I'm new to F# and I'm curious if this can still be optimized further. I am not particularly sure if I've done this correctly as well. I'm curious particularly on the last line as it looks really long and hideous.

I've searched over google, but only Roman Numeral to Number solutions only show up, so I'm having a hard time comparing.

```
type RomanDigit = I | IV | V | IX
let rec romanNumeral number =
    let values = [ 9; 5; 4; 1 ]
    let capture number values =
            values
            |> Seq.find ( fun x -> number >= x )
    let toRomanDigit x =
        match x with
        | 9 -> IX
        | 5 -> V
        | 4 -> IV
        | 1 -> I
    match number with
    | 0 -> []
    | int -> Seq.toList ( Seq.concat [ [ toRomanDigit ( capture number values ) ]; romanNumeral ( number - ( capture number values ) ) ] )
```

Thanks for anyone who can help with this problem.

Comment: Initial advice:  Don't use `Seq` use array everywhere (`Seq.*` functions are significantly slower than `Array.*`.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A slightly shorter way of recursively finding the largest digit representation that can be subtracted from the value (using List.find):

```
let units =
    [1000, "M"
     900, "CM"
     500, "D"
     400, "CD"
     100, "C"
     90, "XC"
     50, "L"
     40, "XL"
     10, "X"
     9, "IX"
     5, "V"
     4, "IV"
     1, "I"]

let rec toRomanNumeral = function
    | 0 -> ""
    | n ->
        let x, s = units |> List.find (fun (x,s) -> x <= n)
        s + toRomanNumeral (n-x)
```

Comment: Maybe `fun (x,s) -> x <= n` can be simplified to `fun x -> x <= n` instead since there's no use for `s` in the function anyway. **EDIT:** After trying it out, since the list is composed of `x, s` units, I guess the lambda is looking for `x, s` as input as well

Comment: I would like to ask what kind of pattern is `n` used for?

Comment: in the toRomanNumeral function n is the non-zero integer remainder to generate numerals for

Comment: @Chad It could be (fun (x, _) -> x <= n) // where the underscore indicates we don't need the value of s.

Answer (score 3):

If I had to use a Discriminated Union to represent the roman letters I would not include IV and IX.

```
type RomanDigit = I|V|X

let numberToRoman n =       
   let (r, diff) =
        if   n > 8 then [X], n - 10
        elif n > 3 then [V], n -  5
        else [], n
   if diff < 0 then I::r
   else r @ (List.replicate diff I)
```

Then, based in this solution you can go further and extend it to all numbers.

Here's my first attempt, using fold and partial application:

```
type RomanDigit = I|V|X|L|C|D|M

let numberToRoman n i v x = 
    let (r, diff) =
        if   n > 8 then [x], n - 10
        elif n > 3 then [v], n -  5
        else [], n
    if diff < 0 then i::r
    else r @ (List.replicate diff i)

let allDigits (n:int) =
    let (_, f) = 
        [(I,V); (X,L); (C,D)] 
        |> List.fold (fun (n, f) (i, v) -> 
            (n / 10, fun x -> (numberToRoman (n % 10) i v x) @ f i)) (n, (fun _ -> []))
    f M
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a tail-recursive version of @Philip Trelford's answer:

```
let toRomanNumeral n =
    let rec iter acc n =
        match n with
        | 0 -> acc
        | n ->
            let x, s = units |> List.find (fun (x, _) -> x <= n)
            iter (acc + s) (n-x)

    iter "" n
```